# Mix comparison of a multiple columns in two dataframe and add a new one using python | pandas

Tags: python, pandas, comparison

I have `file1` that have 6 columns as follow:

```
proNum   proName   color      path    comNum    comName
1        apple     red        ewtt    43        namex
1        apple     red        lfor    27        namey
1        apple     red        bcms    276       namez
4        orange    yellow     owif    7         namea
4        orange    yellow     zxaq    19        nameb
8        burry     bink       lpoq    99        namec
```

And `file2` with 2 columns as follow:

```
comName    color
nameb      red
namex      bink
nameb      black
namez      blue
namec      yellow
namey      red
namez      red
nameb      bink
```

What I'm looking for is adding a column in `file1` resulted by/from: check/go through each value of `comName` in `file1`, compare it one-by-one with `comName` in `file2` if it found the same value then takes the corresponding value of `color` in `file2` and compare it with `color` in `file1` if it's the same put the value of `color` in that new column and exit then check the next value of `comName`.

If the `color` values not equal, keep going in `file2` because `comName` appear one or more than one for some of them, if checking finish in `file2` and nothing equal in term of `color` then put No/Nan in that new column.

Here is the output that should be:

```
proNum   proName   color      path    comNum    comName   New_color
1        apple     red        ewtt    43        namex     No
1        apple     red        lfor    27        namey     red
1        apple     red        bcms    276       namez     red
4        orange    yellow     owif    7         namea     No
4        orange    yellow     zxaq    19        nameb     No
8        burry     bink       lpoq    99        namec     No
```

It seems to be easy but those mixes comparisons really confused me of how to do it, so any help/ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a merge here, that way you only assign a `New_color` when it matches exactly on `comName` and `color`.

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(New_color=df2.color), how='left').fillna('No')
```

#### Output

```
   proNum proName   color  path  comNum comName New_color
0       1   apple     red  ewtt      43   namex        No
1       1   apple     red  lfor      27   namey       red
2       1   apple     red  bcms     276   namez       red
3       4  orange  yellow  owif       7   namea        No
4       4  orange  yellow  zxaq      19   nameb        No
5       8   burry    bink  lpoq      99   namec        No
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying a left join on the tables on the comName and color columns should leed to the desired output

`file2['color_y']=['red','bink','black','blue','yellow','red','red','bink']`
`file1.merge(file2, how='left', on=['comName','color'].fillna('No')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['comName'], keep='last')
result = df.merge(df2, on='comName', how='left', suffixes=('', '_y'))
result['New_color'] = result.apply(lambda x: x.color if x.color == x.color_y else 'No', 1)
result = result.drop(['color_y'], 1)
```

`df` is `file1` and `df2` is `file2`.

**Output:**

```
  proNum proName   color  path comNum comName New_color
0      1   apple     red  ewtt     43   namex        No
1      1   apple     red  lfor     27   namey       red
2      1   apple     red  bcms    276   namez       red
3      4  orange  yellow  owif      7   namea        No
4      4  orange  yellow  zxaq     19   nameb        No
5      8   burry    bink  lpoq     99   namec        No
```